# RestKit not mapping attributes properly when using CoreData

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, core-data, restkit

I am having some issues implementing RestKit/CoreData with my application.  Using the RKTwitterCoreData example application and pointing it to my web service for the json feed, I get the resulting tableview:

[image: Duplicate objects/ID not being displayed correctly]

The issues encountered so far:

1. Refresh generates a new core data entry even though i have primaryKeyAttribute set to the orderID.
2. cell textLabel displays an odd orderID that doesn't match with my web service

Here is my applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Initialize RestKit
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:@"http://mywebservice.com"];

// Enable automatic network activity indicator management
objectManager.client.requestQueue.showsNetworkActivityIndicatorWhenBusy = YES;

NSString *databaseName = @"RKTwitterData.sqlite";
objectManager.objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:databaseName usingSeedDatabaseName:nil managedObjectModel:nil delegate:self];

RKManagedObjectMapping* statusMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Order class] inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
statusMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"orderID";
[statusMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"orderID"];
[statusMapping mapAttributes:@"created_at", nil];

// Register our mappings with the provider
[objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:orderMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/orders"];

// Create Window and View Controllers
RKTwitterViewController* viewController = [[[RKTwitterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController* controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
UIWindow* window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[window addSubview:controller.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

And the json result at /orders:

[image]

Any advice for dealing with this issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! The reason was because the twitter API isn't key value coding compliant.  Once i changed:

```
 [objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:orderMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/orders"];
```

with:

```
 [objectManager.mappingProvider setObjectMapping:orderMapping forKeyPath:@"orders"];
```

It worked again!

Thanks and hope it helps someone.